# MS Word VBA - Centering a Table Needs Manual Refresh: Why and How to Fix?

Tags: ms-word, alignment

This code inserts a table and tries to center it:

```
Sub Macro1()
    wtrows = 4
    wtcols = 3
    Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(Selection.Range, wtrows, wtcols)
    tbl.Rows.Alignment = wdAlignRowCenter  '' centre entire table
    For i = 1 To wtrows
        For j = 1 To wtcols
            tbl.Rows(i).Cells(j).Range.Text = 999
            tbl.Columns(j).Cells.Width = CentimetersToPoints(2)
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

However, the table appears as left-aligned. If I select the table then Ribbon | Home | Paragraph has the Centered toggle button selected (which does not match the appearance). If I force a manual refresh by Control Home/End or toggling Show/Hide Paragraph Marks at Ribbon | Home then the table now appears correctly as centered.

I've tried by code to provoke a full refresh (eg adjust a margin) but nothing works.
How can I force the display to match the table properties?
And any advice on why this is happening?

Word version is 365 MSO (Version 2204 Build 16.0.15128.20210) 64-bit, running on latest Win10.

Thanks.

Comment: I can confirm this behaviour - but didn't found a solution either. Strange ...

Comment: Hi Ike, Thanks for confirming. Worse than not working at all is only fails for me, so a little progress. Reproducibility rather suggests MSWord is the culprit.